# How can we extract numbers from text and numbers data in spreadsheet?

Tags: spreadsheet

I have to work on large spread sheets containing 1000+ columns, so i am seeking a method to extract the phone numbers from middle of data such as, 101 b, Simon road, UK, mob no- 1234567890, middle gate, Birmingham..etc contained in single cell. So i want to pull out the mobile number from spreadsheet and paste to another cell. Please anybody can help me to save the precious time, i had searched the google, but no solution yet.

Thank You.